# Why Facebook login behaves differently between simulator and physical phone

Tags: facebook-graph-api, expo

I have an expo react native app where it uses Facebook auth to login. While running the app on iPhone simulator, I got following error:

```
Error: Tried to perform Facebook login, but no Facebook app id was provided. Specify Facebook app id in Info.plist.
```

And here is the screenshot
[image]

Tricky thing is that if I run the app in the expo app on my physical iPhone, the facebook login has no issue at all. Can someone explain to me why there is different behavior between simulator and physical phone? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more details about the Expo version, SDK and react-native versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upgrade the expo version. Might be you're using older versions of the expo. That's why it is generating an error. I suggest to use expo 36.0.0, I have upgraded from expo 35.0.0. For me, it worked properly.

```
Run expo upgrade in your project directory enter code here(requires the latest 
version of expo-cli, you can update with npm i -g expo-cli)
```